# MySQL REGEXP Get everything between integers

Tags: mysql, regex, between

How could I get all of the contents between single digit integers? Like this string:

```
7get this text9
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `file` REGEXP '[0-9](.*?)[0-9]'
```

But this throws mysql error:

> Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

How do you do this ?

Comment: Yes, `?` is the problem.

Comment: There is no group capturing in mysql regexp, only pattern matching; you should match the pattern in regexp and filter it with a select function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two repetition operators, `*` and `?` following each other.

Removing the `?` would select the text you are searching for.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1183/2)